# Fix button position on different screens

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

How can I make the 0-9 buttons not moved on different screens? I want it in a fix position on different screens.

[image]

[image]

Comment: post your layout xml

Comment: have a look at this libaray https://github.com/intuit/sdp 
if our desired size is 14dp , then use size-2 . 12 for better result .

Comment: @AtifAbbAsi Wow thanks! It's not perfect but it works!

Answer (score 0):

You can make layout with 2 different way 1 with xml and second with program file, In xml you have take all images and layout in one linear layout and divide that layout in "layout_weight"=""number"

If you have to show two image in one row then take

give width to match parent and layout_weight= 1 give width to match parent and layout_weight= 1

//In image give width as matchParent if you want to fit layout on full screen else you can give layout width as wrapContent

Check this code

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="1" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:text="2" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="3" />

</LinearLayout>
```